# Wait for token before making further ajax requests

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, axios

I'm using a class that is wrapping an API. It's utilizing Axios. In order to make requests to the API I require a JWT token that's retrieved via another request using an api key:

```
async setAuthorizationHeader() {
    const res = await this.Axios.post('/login', {
        api_key: ''
    });

    this.AuthToken = res.data.token
    this.Axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${res.data.token}`
}
```

The class is instantiated once the script is loaded and `setAuthorizationHeader` method is run within the constructor, so it sends out a login request at the start. My problem is that if I want to run another API call on page load, I can't as I'll receive a 401 since we haven't gotten the token yet.

Here's another method within my class that I would also be running on page load:

```
async getPromotions() {
    const response = await this.Axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/promotions',
        data: {
            ...this.baseData,
        }
    })

    return response.data
}
```

Is there any way to wait for the authorization step to complete before I run the `getPromotions` request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How and When to use \`async\` and \`await\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)

Comment: So, `await setAuthorizationHeader(); await getPromotions()`?

Comment: @Bergi when I use that I actually end up receiving "Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function"

Comment: Please show us how and where you are running these functions.

Comment: "*`setAuthorizationHeader` method is run within the constructor*" - [don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24686979/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi hmm... I wasn't necessarily returning the promise from the constructor. I was just kicking the method off. I was thinking that I could set a authorizationPromise property on the class to the promise of this method. Does that sound okay?

Comment: @RyanCady Kicking the method off sounds just as bad - better pass the token to the constructor, and kick off the login request before instantiating the class. But yes, you could also store the authorisation promise on the instance, and `await` it in every method that needs to do an authorised request.

Comment: That sounds like what I want to do, however when I'm in the method and I do something like `Class.authPromise.then((res) => { axioscall }` how would I return the promise from that call? Or am I backwards on this haha. I appreciate the help btw

Comment: @Bergi thank you for your help. I believe I've figured this out!

Comment: Yes, you'd either `return this.authPromise.then(() => this.axios(…)).then(res => res.data)` or just `await this.authPromise; const res = await this.axios(…); return res.data;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can store *promise* that is about token's fetching as part of your API object.
2. describe all your other API calls like
       API.tokenLoadingPromise.then(token => // making call with axios

This way you would ensure all your calls are executed only after token is retrieved.

Comment: This is actually what I have ended up doing. Thank you for your help